# How to access an External AppleScript Library from my caller Script

Tags: applescript, libraries

How to access an External AppleScript Library from my Caller Script?

I use the following in my Caller Script:

```
property pExternalLib : ""
set pExternalLib to load script file pExternalScriptFile
pExternalLib's libSetTopMostError("aError")
```

If I end up having to access many other variables and Handlers in my `pExternalLib`, is there a shortcut .. or .. will I have to always prefix the calls for the external variables and Handlers with `pExternalLib's` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `tell` block to direct multiple commands to a script object:

```
    tell someScript
      doThis()
      doThat()
      its someVar
      …
    end tell
```

(BTW, AppleScript has had a native [library loader](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-SW6) since 10.9.)